# HTML required attribute in Django form

Tags: python, django

I have an HTML form which I'm using with a required attribute and I'm using Django to capture the user's input NOT Django generated form but a custom HTML. However, the required attribute isn't working!

Index.Html

```
      <form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate" method="POST"> {% csrf_token%}
            <div class="row align-items-stretch mb-5">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." name="name"/>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." name="from_email" />
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
              
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-textarea mb-md-0">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message *" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message." name="message"></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <div id="success"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" id="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send Message</button>
                
            </div>
        </form>
```

Views.py

```
def index (request) :


        form = contact_form(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.name = request.POST.get("name")
            form.from_email = request.POST.get("from_email")
            form.message = request.POST.get("message")
            
            try:
                send_mail(form.name, form.message, form.from_email, ['test@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
        return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

Comment: What do you see if you `print(form.errors)` *after* the `if`-body, so *before* the `return render(request, 'index.html' {})`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem apparently some JS is missing !
Not Found: /assets/mail/contact_me.js
[24/Dec/2020 03:39:44] "GET /assets/mail/contact_me.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3217
Not Found: /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js
[24/Dec/2020 03:39:44] "GET /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3250
Not Found: /assets/mail/contact_me.js
[24/Dec/2020 03:39:44] "GET /assets/mail/contact_me.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3217

Comment: so in the bakcend you have to check if the form has suche field, and that field is filled or not? if not then raise an error, but there is no problem if you use django form, and set required=True as docs says